# Why is this django formset not being submitted?

Tags: django, submit, formset

i have a formset as follows:

```
EduFormSet = formset_factory(forms.CandidateDegreeForm, can_delete=True)
edu_formset = EduFormSet(prefix='candidate_degree')
```

in the templates i am doing the following:

```
{% if edu_formset %}
{% for form in edu_formset %}
    <div class="formset-form" style="visibility: visible;">
        <form id="{{ form.prefix }}" method="POST" action="/degree/add/">
            <h4>Some Heading Here</h4>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% include "form_field.html" %}
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready ( function(){
                jQuery('{{ form.prefix }}').validationEngine();
            });
        </script>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{{ edu_formset.management_form }}
    <div class="button-container right">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I am not sure why but nothing really happens when i hit the submit button.

Comment: any stacktrace available for python? did you try removing the validationEngine and let django do the form validation instead? Yes, you should.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo No stacktrace, the submit function is not triggered at all for some reason. I  also tried removing the validation engine thing but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button is not within the form, so the action is not triggered by the click!

Here's how [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) show you to render formsets:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <!-- Notice how the formset (below) and thus its submit button
         is INSIDE the form (above) -->
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

You try to create multiple forms with the `form.prefix` for `id`. This could work but each form would have to be rendered with its own submit button. Formsets are designed to combine multiple forms into one and guarantee uniqueness of value names by said prefix. They would be enclosed in a singe form and share any submit triggers.

Comment: i do not want to submit a single form. I want to submit all the forms within the formset.

Comment: I did not know about formsets and just checked the docs. I see they enclose their formset within one html form, which would lead me to stick to my answer...

Comment: so that means i should have all the forms within a form element ?

Comment: posting the docs here is not enough because they are not clear on how to submit the form, hence the question.

Comment: The question was answered in the first line. The copy paste is just a minimal illustration. I'll add a comment for you.